# Is there a suffix "-or-" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-formation

Today, I discovered the work *ankoraŭ* but I confused it with *ankaŭ*. If I correclty understood the meaning of those words:

> **ankaŭ** 
>  In addition to something

> **ankoraŭ** 
>  This word shows a continuity until now

Because Esperanto works with a suffix/prefix system, I want to know if those words follow this kind of rules:

- *ank-* is the root ;
- *-or-* is a suffix ;
- *-aŭ* is the neutral suffix.

But if I believe my theory, **what is the meaning of the *-or-* suffix?** What is the explanation of the construction of those two words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there’s no such suffix as far as I know and *ankaŭ* and *ankoraŭ* are just separate roots. I wouldn’t say that *aŭ* is a suffix either. It is just a common ending for roots where the role of the word is not clear. It still forms part of the root though because for example you can say *ankoraŭa*. In that case you are adding to the whole root word *ankoraŭ* instead of replacing the *aŭ* ending.

Generally the suffixes can be treated as root words in their own right. *Or*’ is already a word which means “gold” so it is unlikely that it would also be used as a suffix with a different meaning.

According to the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ankora%C5%AD), *ankoraŭ* and *ankaŭ* are derived from the Italian words *ancora* and *anche* respectively, so they are not derived from a common Esperanto root.

Comment: While agreeing that *-aŭ* is part of the root, I would like to point out that many people writing poetry in Esperanto (myself included) have occasionally replaced it by an apostrophe: ank’, anstat’ etc. As says http://www.tekstoj.nl/esperanto/konsiloj.htm: ”Kelkaj eksperimentis pri la elizio de -aŭ (ankor', kvaz')”. Yes, I know this is artistic license at its crudest (violating the basic grammar), but I can understand where it is coming from: Appearing in the unaccented end position of a few very frequent words *and* sharing sonic qualities with -o, -aŭ kind of **feels** like a suffix. :-)

Answer (score 2):

-or- doesn't have a meaning in Esperanto. Both "ankaŭ" and "ankoraŭ" are separate roots.

Comment: well, as Neil Roberts points out, or- does have a meaning: gold. :-)

Comment: I meant in this specific context, -or- doesn't have any meaning in the word ankoraŭ.

Comment: – All right, I understand. Sorry if my comment came across as nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who came up with such an idea, but according to Wikipedia, it seems that amoro means ''making love'' or ''intercourse'', as opposed to amo, which means ''love''. So maybe -or- denotes an action related to something?
That would also explain the difference between

```
ankaŭ
In addition to something
ankoraŭ
This word shows a continuity until now
```

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! While this is a nice guess, it corresponds neither with how the language was envisioned and laid out in the Fundamento, nor with how it's commonly used today. Thus I'd say: It's a guess, but it's wrong.